# aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/buster

Tags: raspberry-pi, sublimetext, raspbian-buster

I am trying to install ***Sublime Text*** on my raspberry Pi running ***Raspbian Buster***. So i runned this `sudo add-apt-repository "ppa:webup8team/sublime-text-3For Sublime Text 2"` and get this:

```
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 95, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 599, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 93, in get_sources
    (self.id, self.codename))
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/buster
```

PLease, how do i handle this?
I intend to run this later on:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because the repository you added doesn't know which files go where in Rasbian/buster. However, if you go to https://www.sublimetext.com/download, you will find links to both 32- and 64-bit tarballs of the latest stable build of Sublime Text.

You can expand the archives from the command line (`tar jxvf filename.tar.bz2` or `tar Jxvf filename.tar.xz`) and move the files to wherever you wish - the standard location is `/opt/sublime-text`.

You may not be able to run the files on the Raspberry Pi, because the processor may not be binary-compatible with Intel processors. Sublime Text is not available in ARM or other processor architecture versions, only Intel.

I would strongly recommend NOT installing ST2, as it is obsolete. ST4 is currently the latest version, and has many improvements over ST3.

Comment: you are right, i installed the sublime text 3 as you said but it is refusing to launch

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60595/19512 will guide the way